# Integrar ckfinder con ckeditor

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, ckeditor

He descargado la versión 4.9 de ckeditor y la versión 3.4.2 de ckfinder. El propósito? poder subir imágenes desde el textarea y mostrar el contenido de un artículo con imágenes y videos. EL PROBLEMA? EL CKeditor me carga, pero al darle clic en imagen, debería cargarme la opción de pegar la URL de imagen de manera inicial, sin embargo directamente abre mi gestor de archivos para seleccionar una imagen. Lo que hice fue integrar ckFinder (probé muchas formas) siguiendo los siguientes pasos: http://datoweb.com/post/282-integrando-ckfinder-con-ck-editor-en-la-web
y al subir una imagen me da éxito, pero no muestra la imagen en el contenido, sólo el texto y los videos insertados en código. 
Alguien ha trabajado realizando ésta integración? Estoy trabajando en PHP y MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo implemente el ckeditor y para la carga de imagenes me funciono bien, hice fue lo siguiente agrege en el archivo `config.js`

```
...
    config.filebrowserUploadMethod = 'form';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/ckeditor/upload.php';
...
```

mi referencia fue: https://www.pluginsforckeditor.com/Tutoriales/86/Subir-ficheros-con-CKEditor/es/n86.aspx
donde descarge el archivo  `upload.php` y lo edite agregando:

```
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
$baseUrl = $pageURL.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/ckeditor/uploads/";
```

con esto me funciono espero pueda ayudar de algo